# HTTP verb for increment and get a sequence number

Tags: rest

typically, GET should be to retrieve a resource, but my requirement is to 1)increment a sequence number and retrieve it. From a web perspective, i neither want to make two calls , nor is it feasible, as in concurrent requests, i might get someone's else incremented number. 
So, what i want is atomic (increment and get). What verb or URL technique should i use?

One that comes to my mind is make "incrementAndGetNumber" as a resource itself and then call GET on "incrementAndGetNumber".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a "POST" to the resource with a field called "incrementby" and the response would be 200 OK if everything went well with the newly incremented value as the return value.